# Error while creating directory to store file

Tags: java

I need help to store new folders created according to the current time. After adding the codes for the time, I have received error stating that the system cannot find the path specified.

Here's my current code:

```
public void fileCreation( String fileData ) throws IOException
    {
            String nameOfFile = "c:\\Shane\\Work\\Desktop\\Storage_" + Config.retrieveDate + "\\" + this.nameOfFile + ".csv";
            FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter (nameofFile);

            writeFile.append( fileData );
            writeFile.flush();
            writeFile.close();
    }
```

My Config file has the current line of code:

```
public static String retrieveDate = "";
```

And declaration at another file:

```
Config.retrieveDate = sdf.format(new Date());
```

**Output should be: e.g. ( Storage_20150416082500 ) -YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format.**

Edit

Error occured:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Shane\Work\Desktop\Storage_2015041061404210\Type A.csv (Access is denied)
at test.DataGetter.fileCreation(Retrieval.java:55)`

Comment: Try either debugging or printing `nameOfFile` to see what the value actually is and compare it to your expected value. See what's different and try to figure out why.

Comment: Does this path actually exist on your system?  Open a Windows explorer and paste C:\Shane\Work\Desktop into it.

Comment: is the directory: `c:\\Shane\\Work\\Desktop\\Storage_" + Config.retrieveDate + "\\"` exists? If not you have to create it.

Comment: @Jens has the correct answer here; to solve this problem, you can create a `File` with that path (`File file = new File("...")`) and then call `file.mkdirs()` to ensure all parent directories exist in that file path.  *Then*, you could create your `FileWriter` via `new FileWriter(file)`.

Comment: @Jens is it possible for the program to create the file using my current code?

Comment: No FileWriter can not create a directory. You have to use the approach displayed by Vulcan

Comment: @Jens I've just tired the method but there seems to be an error shown in the console showing this,  'FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter (nameofFile);

Also, this happened before I changed my code accordingly too.

Comment: @user3808244 show the error please

Comment: @Jens updated in post, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the directory `c:\Shane\Work\Desktop\Storage_20150416082500` doesn't exist when you first try to create a file to it.

If that's the case, you should first check if the directory exists and if not, create it. Only then can you create a file within it:

```
public void fileCreation(String fileData ) throws IOException {
    String dirName = "c:\\Shane\\Work\\Desktop\\Storage_" + Config.retrieveDate + "\\";
    File dir = new File(dirName);
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdir();

    //directory definitely exists here, we can create a file to it:

    String nameOfFile = dirName + this.nameOfFile + ".csv";
    FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter (nameofFile);

    writeFile.append( fileData );
    writeFile.flush();
    writeFile.close();
}
```

Of course for that to work, the parent directory (`c:\Shane\Work\Desktop`) would have to exist in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to access an existing file its a good practice to always Try checking if the file really exist or not , you can achieve it by

```
File file=new File(pathToYourFile.extension);
if(file.exists()){
// do whatever you want to do 
}
else{
//either throw any exception or create that file manually if required
}
```

Comment: I think in the OP he is trying to create a new file, in which case `file.exists()` will _always_ return false.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , Rephrased it !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the directories you are trying to create the file in are present, if not present, create.

```
public void fileCreation( String fileData ) throws IOException {
    String nameOfFile = "c:\\Shane\\Work\\Desktop\\Storage_" + Config.retrieveDate + "\\" + this.nameOfFile + ".csv";

    // Make directories if not present
    new File(nameOfFile).getParentFile().mkdirs();

    FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter (nameofFile);

    writeFile.append( fileData );
    writeFile.flush();
    writeFile.close();
}
```

Comment: I seem to have an error including .mkdirs(); (The method mkdirs() is undefined for the type String)
I am pretty new to java and not used this function before, any idea how to solve?

Comment: Oops it was supposed to be `getParentFile()`, corrected the answer, thanks for pointing out.